# wpf,how to restrict MaxLength of TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<TextBox Height="？" Width="?" AcceptReturn="true" />
```

Height=Random;
Width=Random;
For example,Height is 60, Width is 100.
How to control inputed lentgh of text less than size of TextBox

Answer (score 6):

Use [`MaxLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Wait, what? You want to restrict the number of chars to the width of the TextBox? Why that?

**EDIT2:**

You can measure the length of a string by using [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). Here's an extension method that does what you want:

```
public static class TextBoxExtension
{
    public static int VisibleCharCount(this textBox textBox)
    {
        int count = 0;

        do {
            count++;
            var testString = new string('X', count);
            var stringWidth = System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString(testString, textBox.Font);                
        } while (stringWidth < textBox.Width);

        if (stringWidth == textBox.Width) 
            return count;
        else
            return count-1;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
myTextBox.MaxLength = myTextBox.VisibleCharCount();
```

**EDIT3:**

If your TexBox is MultiLine and you also want to take the height into account, you can use the overload of MeasureString that takes a Size. I leave it up to you to modify my example accordingly.

Comment: It is a template of report.user can to draw TextBox. Restrict is to avoid print problem.

Comment: @Arcturus: I corrected the link. This property also exists for the WPF TextBox.

Comment: Nice.. While I am not sure if the Graphics.MeasureString will always produce the correct result still +1 from me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength.aspx) property on `TextBox`, which can be quite static once initialized.

**OR**

You can cancel the text input with the [`PreviewTextInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx) event:

```
textbox.PreviewTextInput += textbox_PreviewTextInput;

void textbox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
   TextBox box = (TextBox) sender;
   e.Handled = box.Text.Length > 5;
}
```

Comment: this is not answer that i want.

Comment: How can to calculae MaxLenth by width and Height?

Comment: Problem is, you can't.. use another Font and all things will be different. Using another OS might even set things off. Your best guess is to use estimates. (lets say each letter is 20 pix, so (width*height) / 20 = MaxLetters). Why do you want to restrict the text anyway?