# How do I limit the number of chars that can be entered into a TextBox? wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I limit the number of chars that can be entered into a TextBox?

```
<TextBox Height="23" Width="160" Margin="5,0,0,5" x:Name="gTBxFind"/>
```

Comment: I understand that sometime is more easy to ask a question here than searching but you really need to learn how to fish.

Comment: @Steve try it. The closest I came was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334792/wpf-how-to-restrict-maxlength-of-textbox, where `MaxLength` is mentioned but doesn't answer OP's question...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.TextBox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Steve I meant _"try to find an SO Q&A that answers this specific problem"_. Without "site:stackoverflow.com" I get plenty of results on Google, but not on SO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MaxLength

```
<TextBox MaxLength="20" Height="23" Width="160" Margin="5,0,0,5" x:Name="gTBxFind"/>
```